# Can I add a margin to <details><summary> elements?

Tags: html, css

I have nested `<details>` elements but I can't figure out how to add a margin to each of the children.

```css
.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.parent,
.child {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <details class="parent">
    <summary class="parent">parent summary</summary>

    <details class="child">
      <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

    <details class="child">
      <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

    <details class="child">
      <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

    <details class="child">
      <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

  </details>

</div>
```

I've tried adding `margin-left: 20px` to the `.child` class and, while it *does* work in codepen, when I load it in Chrome, the elements appear in a straight column.

Am I just missing something really simple here?

Comment: You are adding a margin to `.container` not `.child`.  Adding the margin on `.child` seems to work fine to me.

Comment: I said I tried that and it didn't work.

If it helps to know, all of the elements are being created jquery's with $("").append.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want as a result.

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a parent of `<div class="parent">` having `overflow-x: hidden` like so:

```html
<div class="container_parent">

  <div class="container">

    <details class="parent">
      <summary class="parent">parent summary</summary>

      <details class="child">
        <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

      <details class="child">
        <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

      <details class="child">
        <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

      <details class="child">
        <summary class="child">child summary</summary>child</details>

    </details>

  </div>

</div>
```

```css
.container_parent {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.parent,
.child {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```